# Проверка в цикле на правильность ввода integer

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить числа в цикле, правильно  ли они введены. Мой способ не подходит, так как значения проскакивают. Как быть с этими "проскоками"?

```
int validIntInput()
{
    int num;
    while(!(cin >> num))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore((numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(),'\n');
        cout << "Wrong input. Please, try again: ";
    }
    return num;
}
```

При вводе 1ю2 функция возвращает 1, при вводе 1.2 - также 1. 
Использую так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    numbers[i] = validIntInput();
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Читайте сначала целую строку, а дальше какой-нибудь strtoi64() на том, что вычитали.

Comment: @Regina, не забывайте также о правильной обработке конца файла (`cin.eof() == true`).

Comment: @Flammable, если другого выхода нет, то придется строками делать (хотя мне кажется, что это далеко не самый лучший вариант)

@avp, спасибо, но увы не получилось :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@Regina](/users/18635/regina)](/users/18635/regina), а что именно не получается?

Я бы просто немного изменил цикл ввода для того, чтобы обнаруживать EOF (или поменял прототип validIntInput на `bool validIntInput(int *)`).

Т.е. что-то в таком роде:

```
  int i, iarray[n];

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    iarray[i] = valid_int_input();
    if (cin.eof())
      break;
  }
```

тогда переменная `i` после завершения ввода содержит количество действительно введенных элементов массива.

А функция ввода:

```
int valid_int_input () {
  while (1) {
    int n;
    if (cin >> n)
      return n;
    if (cin.eof())
      return n;
    cin.clear();
    string e;
    getline(cin, e);
    cout << "Invalid input. Ignore [" << e << "] Try again: ";
  }
}
```

в принципе остается почти такой же. Просто добавляется возврат по EOF.

Comment: Спасибо!!!
Теперь разобралась и немного доделала

Comment: хотя..при вводе 1-123 записываются сразу 2 элемента массива: 1 и -123

Comment: Это уже неисправимо в рамках поэлементного ввода.

И кресты и сишный scanf()  считают нормальными

     -3+4-5+6

подобные последовательности.

Тут поможет только чтение целыми строками (getline()) и самостоятельный разбор (например, можно использовать `strtol()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a,b,g,u,x;
    cout<<"a="; cin>>a;
    cout<<"b="; cin>>b;
    cout<<"g="; cin>>g;
    cout<<"u="; cin>>u;
    cout<<"x="; cin>>x;
    double w,v,y;
    w=sin(u-2*g)+pow,sqrt(u+g),g);
    v=pow(g-2*u),2)-u*cos(g)/(3-4*u);
    y=log(tan(a*x))+sqrt(x,7)b*pow),2)/asin(x)-pow(a+x));
    cout<<"w="<<w<<endl<<"v="<<v<<endl<<"y="<<y<<endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @андрій, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.